# Plugin translation not loading from plugin's 'languages' directory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've generated an empty plugin boilerplate from [this site](https://wppb.me/). It includes a [i18n class](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name-i18n.php) to execute the `load_plugin_textdomain` method in order to load the correct textdomain.

This is what's being called in the class to load the textdomain:

```
    load_plugin_textdomain(
        'plugin-name',
        false,
        dirname( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/languages/'
    );
```

When I put the `.mo` and `.po` files for my plugin in the `wp-content/languages/plugins` folder they load fine. But whenever I put them in `wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/languages` nothing except the plugin name and description seem to get translated.

My files are called `plugin-name-nl_NL.mo` and `plugin-name-nl_NL.po`.

`var_dump` on `dirname( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/languages/'` returns `plugin-name/languages/`.

I'm having a hard time debugging this, and don't know where to start.

Comment: Try `var_dump()` to see what `dirname( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )` is actually returning.

Comment: I tried that, updated my question. It returns the relative path: `plugin-name/languages/`.

Comment: Are you sure you need that outer `dirname()`? It seems weird that the relative path is returning correctly, but your files aren't located.

Comment: Yes, the file that executes the method is located in a subdirectory `includes` as can be seen in the repository that the plugin is generated from: https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/master/plugin-name/includes/class-plugin-name-i18n.php

Comment: Ah...that's important information to have. You should add that to the question itself in the event those boilerplate links go dead in the future.